# Сверить два массива с объектами

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

Есть два массива с объектами. Нужно сверить если элементы первого массива есть во втором. 
Пример:

```js
const workers = [
  {
    name: "John",
    salary: 2500
  },
  {
    name: "Jason",
    salary: 3000
  }
]

const companies = [
  {
    name: "BMW",
    workers: [
      {
         name: "John",
         salary: 2000
      },
      {
        name: "Jason",
        salary: 3000
      }
    ],
    description: "some description"
  },
  {
    name: "ВАЗ",
    workers: [
      {
         name: "Вася",
         salary: 200
      },
      {
        name: "Ваня",
        salary: 3000
      }
    ],
    description: "some description"
}
```

Вывести компании у которых есть работники с этим именем и зарплатой меньше чем в массиве workers. У Джона зарплата 2500, а в компании 2000 - значит можно вывести объект из массива с компаниями. В данном случае вывести BMW.

Comment: А вы сами пытались как-то решить эту проблему? Потому что, это по идее делается очень просто, если хотя бы чуть чуть почитать про методы массива

Answer (score -1):

```
companies.forEach(cmp =>                                            /*перебираем массив с компаниями*/                          
    cmp.workers && cmp.workers.forEach(cmpWk =>                     /*в компании перебираем массив с работниками этой компании*/
        workers.forEach(wk =>                                       /*в нём перебираем массив со всеми работниками*/            
            wk.name == cmpWk.name && wk.salary > cmpWk.salary &&    /*сравниваем работников по вашему условию*/                 
                console.log(wk.name, cmp)                           /*выводим компанию*/                                        
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: и что не так...?

Answer (score -2):

```
function checkSalary(workers, companies) {
    let workersObject = {};
    // Делаем из массива объектов workers просто объект с ключом name и значением salary
    workers.forEach((worker) => {
        if (worker.hasOwnProperty('name') && worker.hasOwnProperty('salary')) {
            // Это поможет в дальнейшем избежать лишних циклов для перебора значений
            workersObject[worker['name']] = worker['salary'];
        }
    });
    // теперь в workersObject хранятся такие значения:
    // { "John": 2500, "Jason": 3000 } - обращаться к такому объекту проще и быстрее по ключу, т.е. в данном случае по имени работника 

    // Будем перебирать все объекты в массиве компаний
    companies.forEach((company) => {
        if (company.hasOwnProperty('workers')) {
            // если объект "компания" имеет ключ workers, то перебираем всех работников этой компании
            company['workers'].forEach((worker) => {
                // теперь можно проверять условие основной задачи
                // если у объекта "работник" есть ключ "имя" и это имя содержится в ранее сформированном объекте "workersObject",
                if (worker.hasOwnProperty('name') && workersObject.hasOwnProperty(worker['name'])) {
                    // то далее проверяем, есть ли ключ "зарплата" у объекта "работник" и если, она меньше, чем у работника с таким же именем в объекте "workersObject",
                    if (worker.hasOwnProperty('salary') && worker['salary'] < workersObject[worker['name']]) {
                        // то выводим имя компании
                        console.log(company['name']);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Объяснения бы не помешали)

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko как перебрать массив не понятно?

Comment: Мне понятно. ТС, раз он задает подобный вопрос, может быть не понятно.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko здесь нет сверхъестественных алгоритмов, стандартные методы работы с массивом и объектом, описаны в любом учебнике, в комментарии к вопросу на это уже указали

Comment: То что для вас очевидно и понятно - может быть не совсем очевидно и понятно для другого человека. Ответ дается с 2 целями - помочь ТС и будущим поколениям, которые могут столкнуться с похожей проблемой. В обоих случаях подробный ответ с комментариями лучше просто ответа с рабочим кодом.